# MailAddress vs MailAddressCollection and best use

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My overall goal is to have 1 single "SendIntranetEmail" function in our app code that sends out all of our emails in our intranet app. Right now they are all scattered.

Ideally I would like to pass this "SendIntranetEmail" function the Subject, Body, Footer, and recipients (to, cc (optional), & bcc (optional)), and from (optional). My hang up is how to pass the "SendIntranetEmail" function a list of recipients.

We are using ASP.NET/VB and i'm pulling the email address (from SQL and LDAP) using other functions. Both of these functions return the email address in data tables. So should I pass the "SendIntranetEmail" function an array, or can I send it a MailAddressCollection and/or MailAddress. What is the best way, and how? The array I can figure out. I was just hoping there is an easier way with the MailAddress/MailAddressCollection class.

Thanks
Josh

EDIT - Also, I realize i can pass in the DT to the main function and loop thru the rows. But i'm wondering if there isn't a more efficient way using the Mail class.

Comment: WTH Why the vote down?!!

Comment: i voted the question up.  Good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Joshua, the MailAddressCollection will work fine. Here's an example:

```
Public Class Class1

    Sub init()
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        'load DataTable here

        Dim addresses As New Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            addresses.Add(row("email").ToString())
            'You could also do this for a pretty email name
            'addresses.Add(String.Format("{0} <{1}>", row("name"), row("email")))
        Next

        sendEmails(addresses)

    End Sub

    Sub sendEmails(addresses As Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection)

        Dim mail As New Net.Mail.MailMessage()

        For Each address As Net.Mail.MailAddress In addresses
            mail.To.Add(address)
        Next

        'set message details

        'send mail

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the options you explained, it's a matter of preference (Array, MailAdressCollection, DataTable). I'd go with `MailAddressCollection` just because you get email address validation out of the box the moment you create an instance of `MailAddress`. You can then catch the malformed email and report it before you even attempt to send it to your function.

Comment: I would love to that. That is my preference, but i'm not sure exactly how to do it. How can I get my emails list (from the data table) into this "MailAddressCollection", pass it to my function, and then ".Add" each address in the collection to my (objMailMessage.To.Add) - hopefully this make sense.